# Generic type incompatibility when invoking a method

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface that is named `Record` and another interface `OrganizationRecord` that extends the first one as follows:

```
public interface OrganizationRecord extends Record { /// }
```

I have a function `foo(Map<String, Map<String, List<? extends Record>>> records)`

And I call it with a parameter of type `Map<String, Map<String, List<OrganizationRecord>>>` as shown below:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<OrganizationRecord>>> records = getRecords(); // A function I can't control which returns the map as the signature shows
foo(records);
```

I get the following message:

```
java: incompatible types: java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.List<OrganizationRecord>>> cannot be converted to java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.List<? extends Record>>>
```

What am I missing here? If `OrganizationRecord` is defined as `extends Record` - why wouldn't this invocation work?

I also tried changing the `foo` signature to accept `Map<String, ? extends Map<String, List<? extends Record>>>` because I thought the issue was happening as I may change the maps that are the values to the main keys, but this still doesn't work.

Comment: I think the problem is one of the maps.  Map<Map<Stuff>> is not the same as Map<Map<? extends Stuff>>.  The idea that generics are not covariant applies to the outer Map here.  C.f.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71530768/why-cant-i-assign-a-listliststring-to-a-listlist-variable

Comment: @markspace - Thank you for your comment. So I tried to change the map in the function signature, as mentioned in the last paragraph but still it raises an incompatibility error issue

Comment: I had to use `foo(Map<String, ? extends Map<String, ? extends List<? extends Record>>> records)` - that's three `? extends`. If I omit any of them, I get a compiler error.

Comment: @RobSpoor - You're right! Thank you! If you want to right it as an answer, feel free. I'll upvote and accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use `foo(Map<String, ? extends Map<String, ? extends List<? extends Record>>> records)` - that's three `?` extends. If I omit any of them, I get a compiler error.